# how to echo a message to the terminal window from within a execstartpre command inside a system service file?

Tags: systemd

Everything I have tried either doesn't work or results in an error while starting the service.

This is what chapt GPT suggested and it resulted in an error...

```
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c 'echo "Your message" >/dev/stdout'
```

The error I saw was:

`"/bin/bash: /dev/stdout: No such device or address"`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because From the tag: systemd questions should be for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com. Please delete this.

Comment: You should make note that, on meta, chatgpt recommended not using chatgpt because it is not reliable and often wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In short, **you don't.** Services do not produce interactive output and are not attached to the original 'systemctl' terminal in any way – they're services, and their output goes to the system log (journal). Anything you 'echo' will be visible in `systemctl status` of the service.

(Second, redirecting something to `> /dev/stdout` is completely redundant, as the text from 'echo' is *already* being written to stdout, so you're just redirecting stdout to itself. It's just that the stdout of a service is not attached to your terminal – it's attached to a log pipe.

The redirection fails with an error message because of the strange way /dev/fd works on Linux; it's a bug that went unfixed for two decades and will never be fixed. Services *do* have an "stdout", but it is attached to an anonymous pipe, not a file, and cannot be re-opened the way /dev/fd tries to do it.)

Comment: Bummer, I was just hoping to send a message to future me whenever the service was started. I guess I could probably build a bash wrapper that starts the service it self but didn’t want to do that.

Comment: If it's critical, you could send it to all terminals via `wall`, assuming your terminal emulator opts in (i.e. if the terminal windows show up in `who` or `w`). Otherwise, make something in ExecStartPre that sends you an email or a chat message. (I have syslog-ng set up to forward "alert"-level syslog messages to a Discord webhook, so my tools can do `logger -p alert ...` and it results in a push notification.)